# How to revoke permissions from applications?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, permissions

I don't understand, why some programs are requesting some permissions, especially concerning my privacy.

So I want not to grant them or revoke after granting.

I don't care if application will crash. I expect, that polite application will never access my private data without first asking explicitly. Since I won't permit this, then polite application will never crash. And mutual, if application will crash, then it is not polite and should be uninstalled.

How to revoke permissions on Android?

Comment: You can revoke permissions using the `pm` command (Package Manager). IIRC it should be something like `pm revoke <package> <permission>`. Remember you need run this as root/system.

Comment: I need official non-root solution

Comment: There is none. Except if you install a custom ROM (CyanogenMod) or modify the APK yourself (can be very tricky).